# EKS, how to create 2 LoadBalancer services sharing a static IP

Tags: amazon-eks

Have a 1.18 EKS cluster, with 2 services on different protocol and port, e.g.

```
proc-tcp     ClusterIP   10.100.200.247   <none>         4060/TCP      26h
proc-udp     ClusterIP   10.100.200.20    <none>         4800/UDP      26h
```

How do I convert or recreate them to be type LoadBalancer and share a static IP?

Answer (score 0):

To create loadbalancer, You need to pass

`type: LoadBalancer` instead of `type: ClusterIP`